# Hierarchy/Recursive query on multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

We have a requirement where we need to fetch complete hierarchy of records based on Parent Id. We tried with left outer join but the performance going for a toss and the query became huge.

Oracle version: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0

Say, Product is made up of combination of children, say child1, child2.. child5. And the relation we maintain here is:

```
Product can be direct parent of child1, child2, child3, child4.
child1 can be direct parent of child2, child3 only.
child2 can be direct parent of child3, child4.
child3 can be direct parent of child4.
```

To make it simple have provided the data with 3 tables. _Imed_Par = Immediate parent of child/sub product[image]

```
Table1                 Table2           Table3
Product ProductName    SPB   P_ID       SPC    SP_B_ID  P_ID
P101     Pname1        B201  P101       C301            P101
P102     Pname2        B202  P103       C302    B201    P101
P103     Pname3        B203  P103       C303    B202    P103
                       B204  P101       C304    B203    P103
                                        C305    B202    P103
   Expected Result:                             
    P_ID    SP_B_ID  SP_C_ID    Imed_PAR                
    P101    B201     C302       SPB             
    P101    B204                Product                 
    P101             C301       Product     
    


 --- GETTING FIRST LEVEL ---
select A,B,C, 'PRODUCT' from PRODUCT PR   
left outer join SPB B on B.PRODUCT_id=PR.id
left outer join SPC C on C.PRODUCT_id=PR.id AND C.SPB_ID IS NULL
left outer join SPD D on D.PRODUCT_id=PR.id AND D.SPB_ID IS NULL AND D.SPC_ID IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN SPE E ON E.PRODUCT_ID=PR.id AND E.SPC_ID IS NULL AND E.SPD_ID IS NULL

UNION ALL

--- GETTING RECORDS OF ALL CHILDS WHOSE IMMEDIATE PARENT IS SPB ---
select A,B,C, 'SPB' from SPB B
left outer join SPC C on C.SPB_id=B.id
left outer join SPD D on D.SPB_id = B.id and D.SPC_id is null
--NO SPD JOIN HERE AS THERE IS NO DIRECT AND RELATION SHIP---

UNION ALL

SELECT A,B,C, 'SPC' FROM SPC C
left outer join SPD D on D.SPC_ID=C.id AND D.SPB_ID IS NULL 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SPE E ON E.SPC_ID=C.id AND E.SPD_ID IS NULL 

UNION ALL

SELECT A,B,C, 'SPD' FROM SPD D
LEFT OUTER JOIN SPE E ON E.SPD_ID=D.id AND E.SPC_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: instead of images, please try to put the table content as text

Comment: Is your concern that the query is huge or that it's slow?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Have updated the main question.

Comment: @user3474541, is that one table and you want a query to get the expected output ? I though there was more than one table involved

Comment: @RobertoHernandez My bad. I could have written the table names clearly, have updated  the table names

Comment: @user3474541, where those columns are coming from B_Imed_PAR  C_Imed_par   ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez. Have updated the query for clear understanding, Also, this one has to be calculated by query based on data like " CASE WHEN (SP_C_ID IS NOT NULL) THEN ( 'SP_B')"

Comment: Please share your actual query as well.

Comment: Have updated main question with query..@mohdatif

Answer (score -2):

When the number of levels in parent-child relationships are not known, you can use a recursive CTE approach to solve problems. See a detailed discussions here

https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2

But in the example you gave, it seems the level of parent-child relationship fixed and known. In that case, you can handle it through `LEFT JOINS`. If you're having problem with that, sharing your actual query may help us understand the challenge better.

Comment: Please look at the query in main question where we are joining only on primary keys.

Comment: @user3474541 it wasnt this much clear when I wrote the answer. Deleting my answer.

Comment: @user3474541 On a second thought: I would build a single table with parent-child relations (just the foreign keys, nothing else) and then base my query on top of that to indetify all the relationships from any given level. That's where recursive CTE will help you. What you have is not scalable. The classic example is finding ALL emplyees under a manager (direct or indirect). See similar disucssions from MS SQL but still applies to ORacle https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/39f036f0-b60f-4ff9-84e0-251a2b7a22e1/how-to-find-a-hierarchy-of-employees-3-levels-deep-using-joins